# Error exporting data: Didn't understand relationship 'customObject__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, data-export

I'm trying to export some data from my sandbox org for import into a scratch org, but I seem to be encountering an issue with my query:

[image]

`MediaQualitySetJunction__c` looks like this:

[image]

And this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    (SELECT Id, Name, Width__c, Height__c, Resolution__c FROM MediaQuality__r)
FROM MediaQualitySetJunction__c
```

The full error:

> Didn't understand relationship 'mediaquality__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I'm referencing MediaQuality by the its name on the junction object (with the __r suffix). I've also tried it without this suffix, and with the "Child Relationship Name" I see in Salesforce (MediaQualityJunction), with and without the __r, and I still get the same error.

Based on sfdcfox's answer, I've tried the following export:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -u "aaaaa@bbbbbbb.ccc" -q "SELECT Id, Name, MediaQuality__r.Id, MediaQuality__r.Name, MediaQuality__r.Width__c, MediaQuality__r.Height__c, MediaQuality__r.Resolution__c, MediaQualitySet__r.Id, MediaQualitySet__r.Name FROM MediaQualitySetJunction__c"
```

Which produces the following JSON:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes":
            {
                "type": "MediaQualitySetJunction__c",
                "referenceId": "MediaQualitySetJunction__cRef1"
            },
            "Name": "000035",
            "MediaQuality__r":
            {
                "attributes":
                {
                    "type": "MediaQuality__c",
                    "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/MediaQuality__c/a020p000001WR5oAAG"
                },
                "Id": "a020p000001WR5oAAG",
                "Name": "1080p",
                "Width__c": 1920,
                "Height__c": 1080,
                "Resolution__c": "1920x1080"
            },
            "MediaQualitySet__r":
            {
                "attributes":
                {
                    "type": "MediaQualitySet__c",
                    "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/MediaQualitySet__c/a010p000001O3YZAA0"
                },
                "Id": "a010p000001O3YZAA0",
                "Name": "540p, 720p, 1080p (sandbox)"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then executed the following to import it into my scratch org:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:import -u test-wvcnqftrp5tn@example.com -f "MediaQualitySetJunction__c.json"
```

I've confirmed that I have access to all of the fields involved and that the field visibility is checked for the System Administrator. I get the following result from the above command:

```
{
    "hasErrors": true,
    "results": [
        {
            "referenceId": "MediaQualitySetJunction__cRef1",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "statusCode": "INVALID_FIELD",
                    "message": "Cannot reference a foreign key field MediaQuality__r.",
                    "fields": []
                },
                {
                    "statusCode": "INVALID_FIELD",
                    "message": "Cannot reference a foreign key field MediaQualitySet__r.",
                    "fields": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

MediaQuality__c is the apparently parent of MediaQualitySetJunction__c, so you should be querying it as a parent relationship:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    MediaQuality__r.Name, 
    MediaQuality__r.Width__c, 
    MediaQuality__r.Height__c, 
    MediaQuality__r.Resolution__c 
FROM MediaQualitySetJunction__c
```

Comment: Can I then import the resulting JSON into my scratch org? And is [this documentation example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm) wrong in that case?

Comment: I get the message _"ERROR running force:data:tree:import:  Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from VALUE_NUMBER_INT value 1920 or request may be missing a required field"_ when I try to import the JSON produced by this. I've confirmed that the fields all exist, etc. in my scratch org.

Comment: @John No, the documentation is correct. Broker__c is a parent of Property__c. You had your query backwards (as noted in my answer). In your scratch org, did you make sure all the field level security is set for your profile/permission set? Your JSON might be missing something, maybe you missed a field in your query?

Comment: I've edited my question to include the JSON that is output, and the error I get when I try to import it. I'm also not sure how MediaQuality and MediaQualitySet can be the joint owners of MediaQualitySetJunction.